# on hover animation to table in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

onhover I want animation on table

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
        <th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwKPM.png)
I have added image of what I exactly want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider pseudo element to achieve such effect:

```css
table {
 position:relative;
 z-index:0;
 overflow:hidden;
}
td {
  position:relative;
}
td:hover::before,
td:hover::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  background:yellow;
}
td:hover::before{
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:-50vw;
  left:-50vw;
}
td:hover::after {
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:-50vh;
  bottom:-50vh;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: on hover on smith it should not highlight 50 and jakson

Comment: @itsvinit in this case change change `right:-50vw` to `right:0` and `bottom:-50vh` to `bottom:0`

Answer (score 0):

Use the transition property on the table:onhover selector.

Comment: can u just give the example of which transtion property should i use