# How to set <TR> background color that has <td:active> to different color?

Tags: html, css

During an event that will add "active" class to particular `<td>` cell, I want to set the `<tr>` background to different color when that event happens. For now, I can only set the all the `<td>` cells **AFTER** the `<td:active>`. I want to set it also the `<td>` cells **BEFORE** the `<td:active>`, thus making the whole row changed to different background color.

**Table structure:**

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Expected: When certain event happen**

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
</tr>
<tr> <!-- applied new css during the event -->
  <td style="background: blue"></td>
  <td class="active" style="background: blue"></td>
  <td style="background: blue"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Actual: When the event happens**

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
</tr>
<tr> <!-- applied new css during the event -->
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
  <td class="active" style="background: blue"></td>
  <td style="background: blue"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
  <td style="background: yellow"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to fix my current css styling when the event happens (to achieve "Expected") but I don't know any correct css logic/syntax for it.

Comment: some idea here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54056256/8620333

Comment: Are you adding the class with jQuery? You can define a global color for `td`, add in CSS for `td.active` and you should be good to go

Comment: @Syfer not in my custom jquery. This is purely css only. The logic for this is for my custom weekpicker when I select a date, should highlighted the whole week. This is the minor css issue/logic that I cant solve.

Comment: @Temani Afif I dont understand how it works. And also, im not looking for hover. :(

Comment: you simply need to change the `:hover` with `.active` and it will work the same

Comment: @Temani Afif, I have already changed but it wont work. I have followed Syfer suggestion and it works. Thank your for help tho. :)

Answer (score 0):

I used $('td.active').parent().children().css('background','blue'); and then it works as i expected.

Comment: I'd really be looking at using classes over inline styles.

Comment: this is just a sample simple logic issue solution. I need to use the inline styles for custom. You can use classes for styling if you have similar issue as mine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didnt have any codes for us to work with, here is a small example I just made up. Rather than adding class to a `td` how about add it to the `tr`? It will make it easy to handle it thru CSS. With this you can define more than one class and add based on your preference/requirements.

Below example is adding a class to the `tr` and the rest is done with CSS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( 'table tr' ).hover(function() {
    $('table tr').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
td{background-color:#ff0;}
tr.active td{background-color:#f00;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The above code works on hover at the moment but you can change it to click if need be.

Cheers